# Error con proyecto Meteor "Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink"

Tags: javascript, nodejs, permisos, meteor

Importe un proyecto Meteor y lo quise abrir desde otra computadora, al correr el comando **meteor** sobre la ruta del proyecto me aparece el siguiente mensaje

```
Error: EPERM: operation not permitted, unlink 'C:\Users\Emery\work\meteor\score-keep\.meteor\local\dev_bundle'
    at Error (native)
    at Object.fs.unlinkSync (fs.js:932:18)
    at exports.makeLink (C:\tools\cli\dev-bundle-links.js:20:8)
    at [object Object]._.extend.ensureDevBundleLink (C:\tools\project-context.js:1476:7)
    at [object Object]._.extend._readFile (C:\tools\project-context.js:1410:10)
    at new exports.ReleaseFile (C:\tools\project-context.js:1360:8)
    at C:\tools\cli\main.js:898:22
```

a que se debe este error ya que mi proyecto corre normalmente en la maquina donde lo estuve trabajando

Answer (score 0):

Probablemente una de tus carpetas en la otra computadora se creó como "solo lectura" y por eso te lanza un error EPERM. Prueba buscando la carpeta **node_modules** click derecho - propiedades - desactivar el check que dice "Solo lectura"

Algo así:

[image]